# Authentication and Authorization for a Windows application developed in .Net

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

We are developing a windows application(developed on Mono framework) that works in two different modes. Online and Offline.

In online mode it's having access to API's and DB servers. But when it's in offline mode, the data store is SQLite and everythig happens inside the same server.

Planning to use web api, asp.net Identity and Owin for Security in online mode. Seeking some help to build Autherization and Authentication in offline mode. Is there any packages like asp.net Identity and Owin that can help me in this case?

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869223/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Create-a-Self-Hosted-OWIN-Based-We

I used the techniques here to create a fully fledged OWIN system for a similar purpose. The only thing is, eventually they have to sign on. I have it setup for every 4 days in my projects. So on the fourth day, if the user refuses to connect to my server for provisions I will disable the software until they do.   I didn't use MONO, but hopefully this will get you close to where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am going through this.